# Error php artisan make:migration --seed

Tags: laravel

Hace un tiempo que no pasaba por acá.
Estoy retomando laravel y me he estancado en un error al hacer las migraciones con Factories. 
No me habia pasado esto (en local) de no poder escribir en mis directorios. tal como muestra el error.
Primero tenia error en Course y en Users, pero luego de crear manualmente las carpetas,, ya solo me queda este error en Users.

acá el codigo de error de la consola:

```
fmorales@T460S-FMORALES MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/learning (master)
$ php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrating: 2019_01_07_025001_create_teachers_table
Migrated:  2019_01_07_025001_create_teachers_table
Migrating: 2019_01_07_025926_create_students_table
Migrated:  2019_01_07_025926_create_students_table
Migrating: 2019_01_07_030507_create_levels_table
Migrated:  2019_01_07_030507_create_levels_table
Migrating: 2019_01_07_030840_create_categories_table
Migrated:  2019_01_07_030840_create_categories_table
Migrating: 2019_01_07_030927_create_courses_table
Migrated:  2019_01_07_030927_create_courses_table
Migrating: 2019_01_08_032635_create_reviews_table
Migrated:  2019_01_08_032635_create_reviews_table
Migrating: 2019_01_08_033442_create_table_course_student
Migrated:  2019_01_08_033442_create_table_course_student
Migrating: 2019_01_08_185540_create_requirements_table
Migrated:  2019_01_08_185540_create_requirements_table
Migrating: 2019_01_08_185642_create_goals_table
Migrated:  2019_01_08_185642_create_goals_table

   InvalidArgumentException  : Cannot write to directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\learni
ng\storage\app\public\users"

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\vendor\fzaninotto\faker\src\Faker\Provider\Image.p
hp:72
    68|     {
    69|         $dir = is_null($dir) ? sys_get_temp_dir() : $dir; // GNU/Linux /
 OS X / Windows compatible
    70|         // Validate directory path
    71|         if (!is_dir($dir) || !is_writable($dir)) {
  > 72|             throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Cannot write to
 directory "%s"', $dir));
    73|         }
    74|
    75|         // Generate a random filename. Use the server address so that a
file
    76|         // generated at the same time on a different server won't have a
 collision.

  Exception trace:

  1   Faker\Provider\Image::image("C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\storage\app\public\u
sers", "people")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\database\factories\UserFactory.php:27

  2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::{closure}(Object(Faker\Generator), [
"admin", "admin@mail.com", "$2y$10$3qqQuhlPrWxVASk/Bk8B8.rfKQl94m2AN.OLY6/xl5y4N
GGweqh.u"])
      C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\
Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:274

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.

fmorales@T460S-FMORALES MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/learning (master)
```

Este es mi UserFactory:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Model Factories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This directory should contain each of the model factory definitions for
| your application. Factories provide a convenient way to generate new
| model instances for testing / seeding your application's database.
|
*/

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $name = $faker->name;
    $last_name = $faker->lastName;
    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'role_id' => \App\Role::all()->random()->id,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'slug' => str_slug($name . " " . $last_name, '-'),
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
        'picture' => \Faker\Provider\Image::image(storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'users', 200, 200,'people', false),
    ];
});
```

Espero me puedan dar una mano para resolverlo y continuar.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: seguro que tus carpetas tienen permiso de escritura?

Comment: Pareciera ser un asunto de permisos inicialmente

Comment: SI@shadow
De hecho las carpetas si se crean. Pero los datos de faker no.